# PL/SQL Developer 8.0 LOOP IF ELSE THEN SQL Window

Tags: sql, loops, plsql

I have a **.sql** file created under the **SQL Window** of PL/SQL Developer. It is very loooooog, but basically doing the following:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_1
REUSE STORAGE;
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO table_1
Select * from table2
Where ...;
COMMIT;
```

Before running this script, however, we need to make sure all the sources are readily loaded. So I want to add a logic like below before this script to perform the check:

```
Do check the timestamp field of table1 and table2
If table1.timestamp is NOT today
   If table2.timestamp is today then execute the script listed above
   Else do nothing
   End If
Else do nothing
End If
(Maybe wait for 60 minutes)
Loop
```

I can figure out the LOOP in VBA, but I was more hoping for a way to just add this into the exisiting **.sql** file, or something other ways that doesn't require me to change a lot to the exiting SQL language. **I'm not allowed to use any Program Window in PL/SQL Developer, Unfortunately, since I work in Finance department.**

Does anyone know if there's a way to work out a case like this??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check [LOOP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm#8297) in PL/SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write anonymous PL/SQL block (see oracle documentation for details). For example, it can looks like:

```
declare -- keyword
  /* Here you can declare some variables */
begin -- keyword (starts script)
  /* some statements to do */

exception -- keyword to catch exceptions, if you want to do that
  /* statements to process errors */
end; -- keyword (end of script)
/ /* you need this symbol to show oracle that script body is ended 
     and after this symbol you can write another script, that will 
     be executed automatically after the first one */
```

If you don't want declare any variables and catch errors, you can omit DECLARE and EXCEPTION sections.